# What is the parent when I create an element with document.createElement()?

Tags: javascript

If I create a element using `document.createElement()`, what is its parent? Is it body? Sorry for such a basic question but I've tried using JavaScript to find the parent and it returns an object, not really sure about this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you attach it to something, it is nothing (`null`).

```js
> x = document.createElement("div");
<div>​</div>​
> x.parentNode
null
> document.body.appendChild(x); 
<div>​</div>​
> x.parentNode
<body></body>
```

With regards to your comment, given an array of elements `[x, y, z]`, which may or not be inserted into the DOM, you can  remove those in the DOM as follows;

```
var els = [x, y, z];

for (var i=0;i<els.length;i++) {
    if (els[i].parentNode) {
        els[i].parentNode.removeChild(els[i]);
    }
}
```

... as only elements in the DOM will have a truthy `parentNode`.

Comment: I have an array with many of these elements in. Eg [x, another, another]. How would I go about deleting them if I don't know the parent? Or if I haven't appended them to something?

Comment: @JoelKidd: See my edit. If you've only `document.createElement`'d them, and haven't appended them to anything, the JavaScript garbage collector will delete them once they fall out of scope (e.g. when your function finishes, or when you deference them).

Comment: Thanks very much for adding that to your post. Will select as best answer when the timer is up (and shall also modify question).

Answer (score 6):

The element is created in memory and does not have any parent (yet).

When you place the element in the DOM using `appendChild()` or similar methods, it will have a parent.

JavaScript will return `null` if you try to access an element that doesn’t exist, and that includes parents to elements that only exist in memory.

To access the element, assign it to a variable, f.ex:

```
var elem = document.createElement('div'); // elem is now the element reference
```

You don’t need to explicitly delete elements that you haven’t appended to the DOM as they only exist in memory and will be wiped out once they are no longer referenced.